# C# form - Checkboxes

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox

I'm wondering how to restrict my checkbox from adding to my listbox. At the moment when the user checks the checkbox it will add "Anchovies" to the listbox. What I don't want to happen is when the user deselects the checkbox and re selects it again, "Anchovies" is added to the listbox again (showing two lots of "Anchovies").

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                 {
                     listBox1.Items.Add("Anchovies");
                     double total = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                     total = total + .5;
                     textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
                }            
        }
```

Comment: Well, check if your listbox already contains the value...

Comment: And if the user deselects it shouldn't it dissapear from your listbox?

Comment: Side note: You could make a control that inherits from checkbox that has a property value that would allow you to make a generic checked changed function, as in a string value that holds the different kinds of fish (pizza toppings?)

Answer (score 3):

The key is to check if `Anchovies` already exists on the `listBox1` items.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
         {
             //If the item is already there, we don't do anything.
             if (!listBox1.Items.Contains("Anchovies")) {
                 listBox1.Items.Add("Anchovies");
                 double total = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                 total = total + .5;
                 textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
             }
        }            
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it this way

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
             {
                 if(!listBox1.Items.Contains("Anchovies"))
                     listBox1.Items.Add("Anchovies");
                 double total = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                 total = total + .5;
                 textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to check your list box(for this value, either it is already there or not) before inserting any value in it.

e.g

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items )
{
  if(item.ToString() != "Anchovies")
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add("Anchovies");
  }
  // other code here.
}
```